# Exclude a specific trigger in Undertow server

Tags: regex

I want to remove health check trigger from filters.

So how to exclude `/_health/check` workflow. Tried regex expression `^((?!/_health/check).)*$` but it's not working.

Please help me on this.

I have 4 triggers, all are secured. So when hit one trigger pre filter will execute before entering into actual workflow(/*).

I have another workflow which is health check of my app. It doesn't need any pre-filter. I want exclude this workflow from filter.

Comment: can you add the result which you want to have

Comment: @YvesKipondo i have updated the comment.